# Modify Web.config during/after Web Setup project

Tags: visual-studio, configuration, installation, deployment

How do I modify the web.config of a web site during the setup's execution? 
I would like to have the user construct a connection string and then store that in the web config.

Answer (score 1):

I have found this to work.  But this at run time not set up.

```
public void ChangeAppSettings(string applicationSettingsName, string newValue)
{
    Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

    KeyValueConfigurationElement element = config.AppSettings.Settings[applicationSettingsName];

    if (element == null)
    {
        config.AppSettings.Settings.Add(applicationSettingsName, newValue);
    }
    else
    {
        element.Value = newValue;
    }

    config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified, true);

    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

May be this link will help you: http://aspalliance.com/1220_CodeSnip_Editing_WebConfig_File_for_an_Application_using_Visual_Studio_2005

and

http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Building-a-Web-Setup-that-configures-your-Silverlight-application.aspx